# Not able to post data to mongo db using express API and node JS(Angular4)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I have successfully completed fetching data from MongoDB using express API and node js and binding it to angular ng2-smart-table.
On click of add button of the table, I am calling express API but my post method is not called in api.js, I tried printing console.log inside post but it is not called.
For better understanding hereby I post the code:

***Component.ts***

```
onCreateConfirm(event,_dataService): void {          
this._dataService.postMutualFunds(event.newData);
event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
}
```

***data.service.ts***

```
postMutualFunds(parameterValue:any ){
   return this._http.post('/add_mutual_funds', 
   {params:parameterValue}).map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
}
```

***api.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

 const connection  = (closure) => {
 return
 MongoClient.connect('mongodb://xxx.com:63898/xx', (err,db) => {
 if(err){
        return console.log(err);
    }
    closure(db);
    });
  }
 //Get call
 router.get('/mutual_funds',(req,res) =>{
    console.log("test get"); //This is executed
    connection((db) => {           
    var projection = {_id:0};
    db.collection('mutual_funds').find().project(projection). 
    toArray().then((mutual_funds) => {
           response.data = mutual_funds;
           res.json(response);
       })
     })      
  })

 //Post call
 router.post('/mutual_funds',(req,res) => {
        console.log(req.body.params);
        console.log("test post");
        db.collection('mutual_funds').insertOne(req.body.params)
 })

  module.exports = router;
```

[image]

Now i am able to call the api js but not able to insert the data to mongodb  **please find the screenshot below of the api.js exeution output**
//Why am I not able to post the data?(Updated my post code above) encountering error 500

[image]

[image]

Comment: why are you not subscribing to the service function call `this._dataService.postMutualFunds(event.newData).subscribe((data)=>{ console.log(data);}); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't subscribe to the service

```
onCreateConfirm(event,_dataService): void {          
  this._dataService.postMutualFunds(event.newData).subscribe(    
   (data)=>{
      console.log(data)     
   },
   (err)=>{
     console.log(err)
   }
 )
 event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
}
```

> The service method returns an Observable of configuration
>   data, the component subscribes to the method's return value. The
>   subscription callback copies the data fields into the component's
>   config object, which is data-bound in the component template for
>   display.

Comment: I used your code mentioned above, Now i am able to call the api js but not able to insert the data to mongodb  i updated the api.js code and the screenshot provided of output for further details, It will be helpful if you look into this!

Comment: First , you don't return nothing for the router use   res.json(). second, what is the error details, you check if the data insert successfully to the db

Comment: I tried with this code  db.collection('mutual_funds').insert(req.body.params,function(err,result){

                if (err)
                {
                res.send('Error');
                console.log(err);
                }
             else
               res.send('Success');

            })
I updated the post with the screenshot for error 500 kindly check thank you

Comment: it's look like you don't have connection to db. you didn't use connection((db) => {}  in this route

Comment: I suggest you to create global(singelton) instance that have connection to db

Comment: I have been connecting to the mongoDB in the api.js by this code MongoClient.connect('mongodb://xxx.com:63898/xx', (err,db) => and using closure(db); to access through all get and post most method. The code is mentioned above in api.js

Comment: I found the issue in my updated code above, i was not binding the post method insert code with the instance of db as i did it in get method inside api.js. Now the issue is resolved completely. Here is the missing wrapper inside post method ,  connection((db) => { }) 
  #Thank you for support.

Answer (score 0):

why are you not subscribing to the service function call

```
this._dataService.postMutualFunds(event.newData).subscribe((data)=>{ console.log(data)},
(err)=>console.log(err),
()=>console.log('Observable complete')
);
```

Comment: I used your code mentioned above, Now i am able to call the api js but not able to insert the data to mongodb i updated the api.js code and the screenshot provided of output for further details, It will be helpful if you look into this!